# JBoss 7: how to change a WAR context root

Tags: jboss, war, jboss7.x, contextroot, jboss-web

I have an application that is to be deployed in a WAR file (app.war). After deployment it is available from 
 http://:8080/app 
I would like to have it being made available as something like
 http://:8080/secret/app

I searched the documentation and for JBoss'es 5 and 6 this seems to be able to do with a jboss-web.xml file. I have tried it but with no luck. It seems that JBoss 7 just ignores the  element inside jboss-web.xml.

I don't know if this is relevant but this application has both JSF and PrettyFaces.

Does anyone know if this behavior is possible with JBoss 7? If so, how can it be done? I am still trying to find an answer for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

this works in AS 7.0.1, WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/my_custom_root</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I don't think it is possible to have app root like "server/something/app", but you can simulate this behavior through application structure

Comment: See here for more information and options: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/appdev/jbossweb.html

Comment: In my case, I was working with jboss 6 server and the jboss-web.xml does not exists. I needed creates the file and set the context-root as suggested by you. Works perfect. Thanks!!!

Comment: How can i restrict URL on http://localhost:8080/MyApp on this while application will not update URL

Answer (score 5):

Just for sharing a personal experience...if the context-root in jboss-web.xml seems to be ignored...try to see if it is (the context root) already declared in your application.xml

Comment: I guess `jboss-web.xml` is given a higher precedence. If that is absent, then `application.xml` is respected

Comment: where do I can find this `application.xml`?

Comment: The application.xml is the deployment descriptor of the enterprise application. You can find that in the root folder of your ear