# Setting context-root path in Jboss

Tags: deployment, jboss, directory, external

I want to deploy an application outside the "deploy" folder of JBoss in JBoss 6.0.0
  my folder names must be specified in URL syntax. For example, to specify that C:/rev/deploy be used for deployment,inside deploy folder I placed my war file i.e,ORNC.war so I edited my profile.xml as

```
<property name="applicationURIs">  
            <list elementClass="java.net.URI">  
                <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>  

                <!-- Add your own deploy folder -->  
                <value>file:///C:/rev/deploy</value>  

            </list>  
        </property>
```

After this I restarted my server. Now I am trying accessing: `http://localhost:8000/rev/deploy/ORNC`,

I am getting an error resource not available. How can I acess it? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer my question ,Actually we need to create a jboss-web.xml file with below coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/rev/deploy/ORNC</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

After that I placed this xml file in my WEB-INF folder of my WAR file.Now I can access my war file through http://localhost:8080/rev/deploy/ORNC

```
   By referring this I get an solution for my question
```

[JBoss 7: how to change a WAR context root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232615/jboss-7-how-to-change-a-war-context-root)

```
Thanks for Mr.simkam and Stackoverflow.
```

Comment: Works like charm!